# How to get response value in RestAssured

Tags: rest, testing, automation, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I am doing API automation using rest assured. I want to get value from API response and passed to another java class,

This is my Testing class,

```
 @Test(priority = 1)
    public void UserCreate(){

        Response response = RestAssured.given().when().headers(header.defaultHeaders()).body(builder.UserCreate()).when().post(url);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.body().asString());
        JSONObject getresult = obj.getJSONObject("result");
        JSONObject getperson = getresult.getJSONObject("person");
        Object personref = getperson.get("personReference");

        System.out.println(personref);

}
```

how to change this method is the void to another type or how to pass personref value in another java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is annotated as @Test so it doesn't suppose to return anything.
If you need to use `personref` in your test or another class - create a method for that, ex.:

```
    public Object getPersonRef(){
    Response response = RestAssured.given().when().headers(header.defaultHeaders()).body(builder.UserCreate()).when().post(url);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.body().asString());
    JSONObject getresult = obj.getJSONObject("result");
    JSONObject getperson = getresult.getJSONObject("person");
    Object personref = getperson.get("personReference");

   return personref;
}
```

After that you can call method `getPersonRef()` to get your Object.

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void TestPersonRef(){
Object personref = getPersonRef();
}
```